# 'Use of deleted function ‘boost::weak_ptr' even when I removed shared_ptr's

Tags: c++, unix, c++11, boost, cmake

I am using C++ and my program (it is rather large) worked fine but had some memory leaks which I attempted to fix by replacing some of the raw pointers with C++11 shared_ptr's. Here is an example of a small part of the code

```
void line::addTip( std::shared_ptr<Tip> &t_)
{
    //Tip* t = new Tip();
    std::shared_ptr<Tip> t = std::make_shared<Tip>();
    //t = t_;
    *t = *t_;
    fingers.push_back(std::move(t));    
    //delete t;
}
```

The program again worked fine after replacing some of the raw pointers with shared_ptr's. Then, I replaced some more raw pointers with shared_ptr's, and then I got the error message (I'll show it below). It didn't say where it occurred, so I couldn't figure out where the problem was. I then turned all the shared_ptr's back to raw pointers, but I still got the same error. Here is part of the error output:

```
/directory/build/include/boost/signals2/connection.hpp:150:93: error: use of deleted function     ‘boost::weak_ptr<boost::signals2::detail::connection_body_base>::weak_ptr(const boost::weak_ptr<boost::signals2::detail::connection_body_base>&)’
In file included from /directory/build/include/boost/weak_ptr.hpp:16:0,
             from /directory/build/include/boost/signals2/slot_base.hpp:16,
             from /directory/build/include/boost/signals2/detail/tracked_objects_visitor.hpp:18,
             ...
             from /directory/build/include/boost/signals2.hpp:16,
             from /directory/src/PR/../../inc/ABC/Types.h:31,
             from ...,
             from /directory/src/PR/Spheres.cpp:2:
/directory/build/include/boost/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.hpp:28:25: note: ‘boost::weak_ptr<boost::signals2::detail::connection_body_base>::weak_ptr(const boost::weak_ptr<boost::signals2::detail::connection_body_base>&)’ is implicitly declared as deleted because ‘boost::weak_ptr<boost::signals2::detail::connection_body_base>’ declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
In file included from /directory/build/include/boost/signals2/signal.hpp:21:0,
             from /directory/build/include/boost/signals2.hpp:16,
             ...
             from /directory/src/PR/Spheres.cpp:2:
/directory/build/include/boost/signals2/connection.hpp: In constructor ‘boost::signals2::connection::connection(const boost::weak_ptr<boost::signals2::detail::connection_body_base>&)’:
/directory/build/include/boost/signals2/connection.hpp:153:45: error: use of deleted function ‘boost::weak_ptr<boost::signals2::detail::connection_body_base>::weak_ptr(const boost::weak_ptr<boost::signals2::detail::connection_body_base>&)’
```

...

The full error output is quite large and I could show a link to pastebin if necessary.

Is this just a problem with boost? I'm using boost 1.53.0 with gcc/4.7. Even when I tried Boost 1.54.0, I got the same problem.

I also tried to reset the cmake configuration by creating a new build folder and typing 'make', but I get the error message `directory/src/log4cplus/logger.cxx:27:38: fatal error: boost/current_function.hpp: No such file or directory`. However, I didn't have this error before when building

EDIT: Line 31 of `Types.h` is `#include <boost/signals2.hpp>`. The lines near it are :

```
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp> //line 31
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is around (and including) line 31 of `Types.h` ? (please update your question to include this). The full error on a non-expiring pastebin link may prove helpful as well.

Comment: I think it just contained something like `#include <boost>` or something like that. I can look it up later and get back to you in 30 min or so

Comment: Yeah, was hoping the offending type would be there; alas, tis not

Comment: Since you're having a completely different error after clean build I suggest you to forget this issue for now and focus on the "no such file.." error.

Comment: how can I focus on the `no such file` error? the CMakeLists.txt in directory/project looks like http://pastebin.com/RkxEamgM, if that helps